# The dance of NSFetchedResultsController, NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification, and MagicalRecord

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord, nsfetchedresultscontroller

The problem: I'm getting NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification notifications. I'm merging the changes into my NSFetchedResultsController's context. But the NSFetchedResultsController doesn't fire the didChangeSection, didChangeObject, controllerDidChangeContent methods.

```
self.managedObjectContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context]; //set up my own context to avoid deadlocking
self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Master"];
self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
[self.managedObjectContext setStalenessInterval:0];

//listen for changes in the main context:
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(managedObjectContextDidSave:)
                                                     name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification
                                                   object:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];

- (void)managedObjectContextDidSave:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"[%@ %@] REFRESH!", THIS_FILE, THIS_METHOD); //this happens

    void (^mergeChanges) (void) = ^{
        for(NSManagedObject *object in [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:NSUpdatedObjectsKey]) {
            //this happens (a lot)
            [[self.managedObjectContext objectWithID:[object objectID]] willAccessValueForKey:nil];
        }
        [self.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
    };
    if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
        mergeChanges();
    }
    else {
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), mergeChanges);
    }

}
```

So again, I get the notifications just fine. But my fetched results controller doesn't update. This is killing me! Please help!

EDIT: Also tried this:

```
self.fetchedResultsController = [NSManagedObject MR_fetchController:fetchRequest delegate:self useFileCache:NO groupedBy:nil inContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];
```

Which causes the same deadlocking. If I do this:

```
self.fetchedResultsController = [NSManagedObject MR_fetchController:fetchRequest delegate:self useFileCache:NO groupedBy:nil inContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_context]]; //note that I just changed the context
```

The fetchedResultsController does not update its results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how or on which context you are saving. If you are not saving all the way down to the persistent store, then the defaultcontext is not getting those changes and this your nsfetchedresultscontroller won't update either. You may need to set up a connection between your local context and which ever context the nsfrc is using in order for changes to propagate.